# How to use lightning:input (Beta) for percentages that such a 12.3456%?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The [lightning:input (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) documentation suggests using this markup for percentage input:

```
<lightning:input
        type="number"
        name="percentVal"
        label="Enter a percentage value"
        formatter="percent"
        step="0.01"
        />
```

Changing to this:

```
        step="0.000001"
```

does allow a value 0f 0.123456 to be entered (and preserved) but it is presented when focus moves away from the field as 12% not 12.4567%.

If there a way to include the extra digits?

(Following the call through in the JavaScript debugger, a fixed underlying formatter called "currencyUSDstylepercent" is used with no reference to the `step` parameter so I'm assuming the answer to my question is no.)

Comment: I traced the same thing but the moment you add formatter as "percent" it add thats rounding to percentage thing. You can probably add a hidden field and toggle and show that between read and edit mode. In read it shows a p tag with the value you want and in edit mode they can edit and change the value as they wish.